# Использование акселерометра

Tags: java, android, аудио, mediaplayer

Я пытаюсь реализовать в своём приложении идею последовательного наложения звуков друг на друга при использовании акселерометра и mediaplayer, то есть чем сильнее трясёшь свой телефон (тем больше переменная speed), тем больше накладывается звуков друг на друга. Так же с уменьшением тряски они начинают отключатся в том же порядке, что и воспроизводились.

Строчки кода:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spd);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mp[0] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arb0);
    mp[1] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arb3);
    mp[2] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arb10);
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 1) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

            textSpeed.setText("speed:" + speed);

            if (speed > 600) {
                text1.setText("Unlock");
                mp[0].start();
                if (speed > 800) {
                    text2.setText("Unlock2");
                    if (!mp[1].isPlaying()) {
                        mpSecto = mp[0].getCurrentPosition();
                        mp[1].seekTo(mpSecto);
                    }
                    mp[1].start();
                    if (speed > 1000) {
                        text3.setText("Unlock3");
                        if (!mp[2].isPlaying()) {
                            mpSecto = mp[1].getCurrentPosition();
                            mp[2].seekTo(mpSecto);
                        }
                        mp[2].start();
                    }
                }
            } else if (speed < 600) {
                text1.setText("");
                mp[0].seekTo(0);
                mp[0].pause();
                if (speed < 800) {
                    text2.setText("");
                    mp[1].seekTo(0);
                    mp[1].pause();
                    if (speed < 1000) {
                        text3.setText("");
                        mp[1].seekTo(0);
                        mp[1].pause();
                    }
                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    last_z = z;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что если в условии установить значение speed допустим 1500 или 2000 и т.д., то звук не воспроизводится, хотя надпись "unlock" появляется; если убрать условия, при которых звук отключается, то есть speed < 1000, 800 и 600, то звук спокойно воспроизводится и при значении speed > 4000 и 8000. Так как для моей реализации значения от 0 до 1000 очень малы, мне нужно использовать значения от 1000 до 10000, то есть "тряска" телефона должна быть сильной, может кто что подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня мне нечего делать, потому вместо ответа на невнятно сформулированный вопрос попробую написать что-то вроде памятки.

**Датчики**

Работа с датчиками, такими как акселерометр, всегда сложна. Во-первых, надо постоянно имитировать нужные условия (трясти его), поддерживать эти условия (трясти с нужной скоростью) и быть уверенным в корректности работы оборудования (к примеру, на моем планшете акселерометр переодически отваливается до перезагрузки планшета, данные могут быть некорректны из-за загрузки процессора и т.д.). Учитывая все эти условия, отладка приложений, работающих с датчиками, может превратиться в БОЛЬ И УНИЖЕНИЯ. Поэтому код для работы с датчиками как правило как-то изолируют, парсят данные и уже потом, в отдельном куске кода их как-то используют. Это же позволяет эмулировать данные с датчиков, чтобы можно было отлаживаться на чем-то стабильном и лишний раз не трясти планшет.

В твоем случае, я бы эмулировал скорость при помощи синусоиды, зависящей от времени. Берем таймштамп, делим на что-то большое (подобрать экспериментально), берем синусоиду, помножаем на примерный максимум, что может быть получено с акселерометра и наблюдаем за цифирками. Результат суем в функцию, которая должна принимать показания датчика и отлаживаемся до тех пор, пока не понравится. Вполне может быть так, что программа написана корректно и хорошо, просто датчик (или код его обработки) работает некорректно. Отлаживать такую программу будет много проще, причем для этого не нужен ни планшет, ни крутая ИДЕ, ни отладчик - достаточно консоли и принт-ов.

**Индентация кода**

Или просто отступы в коде. В принципе, это совершенно ненужная хрень, на которую можно не обращать внимания. На работу кода оно не влияет, потому совершенно нет нужды расставлять эти пробелы или табы по всему коду (исключение - так называемый язык программирования "питон", который я именно из-за этого за язык не считаю).

И если ты мегамозг и держишь логику работы кода в голове, а на экране лишь его жалкая проекция - все хорошо. А вот если ты не понимаешь как оно работает, или вообще даешь читать код кому-то еще, коллеге по работе, или вот сюда в стековерфлоу выкладываешь, то его неплохо бы отформатировать. В нормальных редакторах кода есть специальная кнопочка, а если нет - есть куча сайтов вроде http://jsbeautifier.org/, давай посмотрим что оно сделало:

```
if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
    float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 1) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

        textSpeed.setText("speed:" + speed);

        if (speed > 600) {
            text1.setText("Unlock");
            mp[0].start();

            if (speed > 800) {
                text2.setText("Unlock2");
                if (!mp[1].isPlaying()) {
                    mpSecto = mp[0].getCurrentPosition();
                    mp[1].seekTo(mpSecto);
                }
                mp[1].start();
                if (speed > 1000) {
                    text3.setText("Unlock3");
                    if (!mp[2].isPlaying()) {
                        mpSecto = mp[1].getCurrentPosition();
                        mp[2].seekTo(mpSecto);
                    }
                    mp[2].start();
                }

            }

        } else if (speed < 600) {
            text1.setText("");
            mp[0].seekTo(0);
            mp[0].pause();
            if (speed < 800) {
                text2.setText("");
                mp[1].seekTo(0);
                mp[1].pause();
                if (speed < 1000) {
                    text3.setText("");
                    mp[1].seekTo(0);
                    mp[1].pause();

                }

                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                last_z = z;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Первым делом в глаза бросается лесенка из условий. Зачастую это признак плохого кода (но совершенно не обязательно, что код с лесенкой - плохой).

Давай посмотрим, как работает основная развилка:

```
if (speed > 600) {
    ...
} else if (speed < 600) {
    ...
}
```

С человеческой точки зрения, код - прост, понятен, идеален. Но что будет, если speed=600? А ничего не будет, такая скорость вообще не будет никак обработана. К счастью, с датчиков такой результат будет приходить крайне редко и на этот мелкий баг можно наплевать. Бывают конечно ситуации, что потом с голой задницей ищешь такие баги месяцами, а найти их не получается, но это не наш случай.

Смотрим на лесенку дальше:

```
if (speed > 600) {
    ...
} else if (speed < 600) {
    if (speed < 800) {
            ...
        if (speed < 1000) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Что будет, если speed=700? Выполнится первое условие. А чтобы попасть во вторую часть лесенки, значению нужно быть менее 600. И проверки на "менее 800" и "менее 1000" просто не имеют никакого смысла, так как значение и так меньше этих чисел.

Хм... Похоже надо переписать всю логику! Ведь именно это делает программист, правда?

**Мультимедия**

Старт-стоп мультимедии, к примеру проигрывание рингтона - достаточно сложная задача. То, что проиграть мелодию в современных фреймворках можно всего 1 командой - достаточно сильно развращает программистов и отучает думать о том, что же система будет делать на самом деле для запуска.

Очень часто мультимедийные объекты:

1. Нельзя запускать, когда они уже запущены
2. Старт-стоп дорогая операция, зато часто есть дешевая пауза
3. Не дали паузы? Убавь громкость до 0, но не останавливай поток!
4. Перемотка не поддерживается
5. Перезапуск не поддерживается

Не обязательно, что все будет так плохо, вполне возможно что используемый фреймверк имеет защиту от дурака. Но это надо помнить. Из этого часто рождаются разные уловки, такие как пулы готовых к воспроизведению объектов, которые уже почти запущены, но ожидают своей наносекунды.

Так как у нас в пункте 1 был совет сделать эмулятор датчика на основе синусоиды, в пункте 2 мы переписали логику, то уж теперь мы точно сможем понять, есть ли у нас проблема с воспроизведением звука или нет...

Comment: Конечно можно долго филосовствовать,что должен или не должен уметь хороший программист,что отличает хорошего от плохого.Конечно идеальный программист, который силой мысли пишет код без единой ошибки,параллельно играя в x-box,Да, датчики это сложное устройство,не учитывая,что в телефонах они установленны самые дешёвые за 1-2$,но в моей реализации и не требуется какая та повышенная точность,вроде того,что бы speed была прям равна 600,нет,она или больше этого значения или меньше.Можно расписать целую поэму,суть которой:"я ничего тут не понял",но если speed>1000,звук перестаёт воспроизводится,всё

Comment: Ах,да,если speed=700,то будет выполняться условие if(speed<600),это не сложно...start и pause работают корректно,и в моём исполнении как раз нужна перемотка,а не затухание звука,и оно работает хорошо,если если в условии speed задано от 0 до 1000,а вот если мы задаём в условии speed от 1000 и выше,то звук уже не воспроизводится,если только не убрать pause,если убрать,то воспроизведение вновь появляется,это не сложно и это описано выше